# HUAWEI Connect API - Reviews- 403 response code

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I was trying to query the /API/reviews/v1/manage/dev/reviews, but with my authorization, I am getting a 403 error. I am using developer users to query this.

Comment: I am able to query with 200 response code. But now, post which I am not able to see any comments. For example, I tried from Jan 01,2021 to Mar 30,2021 for the App Id =101352789.But the result is returning nothing.

 

Could you please let me know if any URL changes done or version chnages need to be made. I am receiving nothing.

I did for all countries regionwise as well and separately as well, receiving empty response.

Request :



{"ret":{"rtnCode":0,"rtnDesc":"success"},"data":{"reviewList":[],"hasNext":0,"total":0}}

Answer (score 0):

The Comments API can be accessed only through the API client mode. To access the API, you need to obtain authorization from the server. The authorization process consists of API client creation and access token obtaining. For details, please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-getstarted#apiclient

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-comments-api-overview

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below domain details:

Domain name for China: connect-api.cloud.huawei.com

Domain name for Germany: connect-api-dre.cloud.huawei.com

Domain name for Singapore: connect-api-dra.cloud.huawei.com

Domain name for Russia: connect-api-drru.cloud.huawei.com

As you’re requesting url, is china domain: https://connect-api.cloud.huawei.com/api/reviews/v1/manage/dev/reviews  but all the country you are querying are from Singapore.
For more info, please refer to the guidelines.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-getreviewdetailinfo

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-getreviews

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-reference-countrycode